# $location.path causes a full page refresh

Tags: angularjs

I have a page with a link. If the user clicks on the link a popup will display, using ng-show. This is the **ng-click**:

```
<div class="adItem" ng-click="showArticleMethod(tiki._id, tiki.tikiTitle)" ng-repeat="tiki in tikis track by tiki._id">
```

On click a **showArticleMethod** gets called in the controller:

```
$scope.showArticleMethod = function(tikiID, article){

    var title = $filter("underscoreString")(article)
    $location.path(tikiID + "/" + title)

    $scope.showArticle = tikiID

}
```

The method also changes the url to: **`index.html#/1/title`** using $location.url().

Since i want people to be able to directly link to the article i have set up this route:

```
$routProvider.when("/", {

    templateUrl: "partials/promise.html",
    controller:"tiki.controllers.promise",
    reloadOnSearch:false

}).when("/:id/:title/", {

    templateUrl:"partials/promise.html",
    controller:"tiki.controllers.promise",
    reloadOnSearch:false
```

}

Everything works fine except the animation (opacity:0 to opacity:1) that is set on the popup **does not work**.

My guess is that the url is not just changed but also reloaded so i tried adding '**reloadOnSearch:false**' but that doesn't have any effect.

How can i change the url without reloading the url and keeping the css animation?

**This is my full controller:**

```
/* Controllers */
angular.module('tiki.controllers').controller("tiki.controllers.promise", ["$scope", "tikiDB", "$routeParams", "$filter", "$location", function($scope, tikiDB, $routeParams, $filter, $location){

    $scope.tikis = tikiDB.query()
    $scope.location = ""

    $scope.showArticleMethod = function(tikiID, article){

        var title = $filter("underscoreString")(article)
        $location.path(tikiID + "/" + title)

        $scope.showArticle = tikiID

    }

    $scope.hideArticleMethod = function(){

        $location.path("")
        $scope.showArticle = false

    }

    if($routeParams){

        $scope.showArticle = parseInt($routeParams.id);

    }

}])
```

The variable '`showArticle`' is set to '`false`' if no article is shown. It is set to the `article ID` if an article has to be shown. The article is shown in a popup that is activated using a class that is added to the `<body>` tag.

```
<body ng-class="{'bodyShowArticle': showArticle}" ng-view="">
```

If i add a $timeout then the animation works again but does a full page refresh after the timeout:

```
    $timeout(function(){

        $location.path(tikiID + "/" + title)

    }, 1000)
```

Comment: something else must be happening, because the documentation on $location states very clearly that "The `$location` service allows you to change only the URL; it does not allow you to reload the page. When you need to change the URL and reload the page or navigate to a different page, please use a lower level API, `$window.location.href.`" https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#!

Comment: indeed, that's why i don't understand why this is happening...